# Query Sum of two fields based on a value using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Basically, I have an array of objects with nested arrays of objects. I want to query the data based on the `"userID"` and sum of `"flashcardReversed.value" + "flashcardReversed.count"`.

The user will provide the userID and a (value + count) value that is desired.

Here is my data:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": "608642db80a36336946620aa",
    "userID": "user1",
    "title": "title2",
    "flashcardReversed": [
      {
        "_id": "608d5b290e635ece6828141X",
        "front": "2front",
        "back": "2back",
        "value": 1,
        "count": 2
      },
      {
        "_id": "608t5b290e635ece6828141Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed",
        "back": "2backReversed",
        "value": 2,
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253726X",
        "front": "2front2",
        "back": "2back2",
        "value": 3,
        "count": 4
      },
      {
        "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253726Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed2",
        "back": "2backReversed2",
        "value": 4,
        "count": 5
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "608642db80a36336946620aa",
    "userID": "user1",
    "title": "title3",
    "flashcardReversed": [
      {
        "_id": "608d5b290e635ece6828142X",
        "front": "2front",
        "back": "2back",
        "value": 12,
        "count": 6
      },
      {
        "_id": "608t5b290e635ece6828143Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed",
        "back": "2backReversed",
        "value": 21,
        "count": 7
      },
      {
        "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253727X",
        "front": "2front2",
        "back": "2back2",
        "value": 34,
        "count": 8
      },
      {
        "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253729Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed2",
        "back": "2backReversed2",
        "value": 42,
        "count": 9
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "608642db80a36336946620aa",
    "userID": "user2",
    "title": "title4",
    "flashcardReversed": [
      {
        "_id": "608d5b290e635ece6828131X",
        "front": "2front",
        "back": "2back",
        "value": 41,
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "_id": "608t5b290e635ece6828161Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed",
        "back": "2backReversed",
        "value": 54,
        "count": 11
      },
      {
        "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253526X",
        "front": "2front2",
        "back": "2back2",
        "value": 63,
        "count": 12
      },
      {
        "_id": "608a5b31a3f9806de253326Y",
        "front": "2frontReversed2",
        "back": "2backReversed2",
        "value": 29,
        "count": 13
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For example the query should like:

```js
{
  "userID": {"$eq": provided_user_id}
  {"flashcardReversed.value" + "flashcardReversed.count"}: {"$eq": provided_value_plus_count}
    }
```

Is it possible to achieve this using pymongo?

Comment: The output is broken (missing some commas after fields) but also `_id` is the same for all three docs -- assuming they are supposed to be three separate docs in the collection and not an array of 3 items in 1 doc.   Also: do you want to match against the sum of all the docs found for a user, or per doc  (your data suggests userID can show up in multiple docs).   Clarify, please.

Comment: json was not valid if you can use something like [this](https://jsonformatter.org/json-pretty-print) to check it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the uniqueness here is `userID+title` and we want to agg across both the `flashcardReversed` field and multiple `title` i.e. getting to one number for a user, then this is a solution.

```
var targetUser = "user1";
var targetAmt = 163;

c = db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {"userID": targetUser}} // will fetch one OR MORE records...                                       
    ,{$addFields: {
        X: {$reduce: {
            input: "$flashcardReversed",
            initialValue: 0,
                // $$value is the running result of the reduce operation ($add)
                // $$this is the current object from the array; it just so
                // happens that a field in your object is named "value" so
                // do not confuse the two.  The expression below translates
                // to:  n = n + oneitem.value + oneitem.count
                in:{$add: [ "$$value", "$$this.value", "$$this.count" ] }
        }}
    }}

    // Now, add up X over multiple docs.  We can group by null because we                                       
    // know ONLY docs where userID = targetUser are coming through:                                             
    ,{$group: {_id: null, n: {$sum: "$X"}}}

    // ...and match against input:                                                                              
    ,{$match: {n: targetAmt}}                                                                                 
]);
```

The solution above demonstrates the individual `$reduce` and `$group` behaviors but these can be combined.  Also, let's explore what would need to be done to fetch multiple users for a target amount:

```
var targetUser = ["user1","user2"];
var targetAmt = 163;

c = db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {"userID": {$in: targetUser}}}                                 

    // Combine the $group and $reduce together.  Saves a stage!  Also, since                                    
    // more than one userID can come through, we must change _id to group                                       
    // by $userID instead of null:                                                                              
    ,{$group: {_id: "$userID", n: {$sum: {$reduce: {
            input: "$flashcardReversed",
            initialValue: 0,
                in:{$add: [ "$$value", "$$this.value", "$$this.count" ] }
    }} }  }}

    // Probably want to use >= or <= instead of exact match sometimes                                           
    // so here is an example of that:                                                                           
    ,{$match: {$expr: {$gte: ["$n", targetAmt]}} }
]);

{ "_id" : "user1", "n" : 163 }
{ "_id" : "user2", "n" : 233 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

- match on userid
- filter the array and keep only members that `(= (+ value count) 3)`
- you can replace the 3 with the variable or any number
- if after filter the array is empty, document is rejected
- in final results we keep in the array only those that pass, and only the documents that have at least 1 member that pass

*not sure if you want this

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70307275)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"userID": {"$eq": "user1"}}},
 {"$set":  
   {"flashcardReversed": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$flashcardReversed",
        "cond": 
        {"$eq": [{"$add": ["$$this.value", "$$this.count"]}, 3]}}}}},
 {"$match": {"$expr": {"$ne": ["$flashcardReversed", []]}}}])
```

Comment: Hi @Takis_, yes the solution works correctly. But, it only returns from one of the object. Let's say there are two objects with userID as user1 and both of them have some flashcardReversed objects with value and count sum as 3. Your query only returns the flashcardReversed objects from one of the object. Here https://cmql.org/play/?q=1639239808949, you can see what I am trying to say.

Comment: i saw what you mean but in your sample data you had the same `_id` and this wasn't working in MongoDB(only 1 was inserted), i re-run it after fixing that, and i took [this](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70307275) that looks ok has both objects, if you don't like this you can `$unwind` also the array, if you are stuck send the expected output so we know what you need exactly